Old GCC 4.4.7 wasn't initializing randomly
I was compiling C legacy projects using:
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313

On a RedHat6 environment, pretty old.
Now I'm using:
gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514

On a RedHat8 environment, which is better.
Flags were:
-Wl,-s -m32 -o $@ Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Warray-bounds -ftree-vrp

Only diff is I needed to add ""lm", now:
-Wl,-s -m32 -o $@ Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Warray-bounds -ftree-vrp -lm

Executing the same executable and debugging it using -ggdb3 / -O0 shows:
On the RH6 old env / old exe:

On the RH8 old env / old exe:

Causing major issues in lot of part of our legacy applications.
Do you have any ideas of why the behavior has changed ?
New GlibC is:
(GNU libc) 2.28
Old GlibC was:
(GNU libc) 2.12

Sounds like undefined behavior from reading uninitialized variables, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the code.  If that's the case, you need to initialize variables before you read them.

Try char VL_Extend[8] = {0};

An raw dump in octal format is far from helpful...

Anyway the by far most likely reason is that you have code relying on undefined behavior and now the bugs that were always there surfaced. But also gcc from version 8 somewhere started to become a veritable bugfest. There's no stable version any longer, it's all experimental beta stuff filled with bugs. So if you can still use version 4.x something, stick with it.

@dbush Yes those are just variables non-initialized like in pmg example. (char VL_Extend[8];), where behavior seems to have changed.

@pmg I'll try that and see how far is gets thanks

@Lundin do you know if we can still use GCC 4.x on newer linux distributions or this is a bad idea ? Which dump format would you rather use ? It's the gcc backtrace output

@Retsim I have no idea, Linux programming is not my cup of tea. But gcc 4.x is from somewhere around early 2010s so it's hardly ancient. It will have limited C11 support and wouldn't be recommended for stuff like _Generic (which had language defects up to C17), but otherwise far more stable than all the blatantly dangerous experimental versions from 10 and beyond.

@Retsim Shouldn't it be -Wuninitialized rather than Wuninitialized?

For professional use I'm using gcc 7.2.1 (arm-none-eabi) which is apparently the latest one we've considered stable enough for use in the real world. For playing around, I always use the latest gcc (trunk/14.2).
